# Magento2 multiple websites

Tags: magento2, websites, base-url

I have the fallowing domains:

```
www.test1.mydomain1.com
www.test2.mydomain2.com
```

I've created the websites and the stores that are attached to them.
From the admin panel I changed the Base URL and Base URL Link
of website1 to

```
http://test1.mydomain1.com
```

And for website2 to

```
http://test2.mydomain2.com
```

In pub/index.php I added the fallowing

```
$test1 = array('test1.mydomain1.com');
$test2 = array('test2.mydomain2.com');
if(in_array($params['SERVER_NAME'],$test1)){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website1';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}
else if(in_array($params['SERVER_NAME'],$test2 )){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}
```

Still, when I go to www.test1.mydomain1.com everything is broken. The CSS and javascript files are not loaded apparently, and the console in dev tools shows errors like:

```
GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/css/animate.css 
(index):18 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/css/styles-m.css 
(index):21 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css 
(index):20 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css 
(index):17 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/mage/calendar.css 
(index):19 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css 
(index):24 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/icon-fonts/css/porto-icons-codes.css 
(index):25 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/icon-fonts/css/animation.css 
(index):27 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/Smartwave_Filterproducts/css/filterproducts.css 
(index):23 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox.css 
(index):26 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/css/custom.css 
(index):28 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/css/styles-l.css 
(index):131 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/media/porto/configed_css/design_mshop_swe.css 
(index):132 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/media/porto/configed_css/settings_mshop_swe.css 
(index):30 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/requirejs/require.js 
(index):31 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 
requirejs-config.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:18(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:19(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:601
(index):34 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
(index):35 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js 
(index):33 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/jquery.js 
(index):42 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):42
(index):134 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):134
(index):143 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):143
(index):362 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):362
(index):348 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):29 GET http://test1.mydomain1.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/sv_SE/css/print.css
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this solution http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html is correct. The problem was in the ready theme for Magento2 I've bought.. it broke like half of the features. Consider this matter closed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create sub folders in pub example

pub/website1

it should have index.php with following code

try {
require **DIR** . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
 exit();
}

$params = $_SERVER;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website1';

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);

and your htaccess in this folder pub/website1
must have

RewriteBase /website1/

I hope this solves your problem. With this you can discard your changes of pub/index.php

Comment: same thing, no change... Should I somehow recreate the other folders in pub or.. ?

Comment: apart from this, I guess you should refer to server settings.

Comment: please check http://blog.belvg.com/multistore-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: yes, I did that. it is really weird, i fallow the documentation exaclt from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html and everything is broken. I really hate this sh*t ... really

Comment: scratch that.. the whole problem was in the stupid Magento2 theme I've bought.. it actually broke everything... amazing, 10x for the help anyway